# Java regex find symbols in a string

Tags: java, regex, symbols

I'm looking for some explanation for Java regex. I have read and tried different tutorials, but my code doesn't want to work.

```
String myString = "JKAE[JKk]jkhe{kjef}kaejf-aef_a|ef=kjef+kejf\akejf/efj:efa;aef'asd"fd,<ef>";

if( myString.matches(".*[\\[|]|\\{|\\}|-|+|\\\\|;|:|\\'|\\"|<|>|/") ){
   log("something");
   return;
}
```

Only alphanumeric characters is allowed, inclusive "." [dot]
Symbols not allowed: -_=+\|[{]};:'",<>/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a little hard to tell what you want, so here's two options:

For only alphanumeric and the dot:

```
if (!myString.matches("[a-zA-Z0-9.]*") {
    // contained an invalid character
}
```

To disallow the characters you listed:

```
if (!myString.matches("[^-_=+\\\\|\\[{\\]};:'\",<>/]*") {
    // contained an invalid character
}
```

Comment: I think first approach is more preferable.

Comment: @smit I think so too - for one you can *read* the damn regex! I just wasn't sure since he mentioned the characters he *didn't* want. Had he left that out, the first answer would be the only sane answer.

Comment: Shouldn't that be [a-zA-Z0-9\\.]?  Using just . would be a wildcard

Comment: @Alex No. Characters lose all special regex meanings inside a character class, except for the hyphen and backslash. Here, a dot is just a literal dot